# Migration from GCM to FCM. New token generated on device but old still seems to be valid

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problem with tokens generated in FCM (or previously GCM).

We just migrated from GCM to FCM in our Android app and all users seems to get a new token generated on app start after update.
This causes som trouble since we store the tokens on our server for a users all devices and since we got a new token when migrated this is stored as a new device for that particular user.

**The problem is that the old GCM token still seems to work and all users are now getting double push notifications to the same device..**

**Here is a use case:**

1. User installed the app on 1 phone and 1 tablet (GCM version of app)
   Server now contains these tokens for user:

Tablet: evWLQAq2yXw:APA91bH4GlHPSi[...]

Phone: *fnLVyZy_ICE*:APA91bHopxcL1ckHl[...]

2. User upgrades to new version on phone (FCM version of app which generates a new token)
   Server now contains these tokens for user:

Tablet: *evWLQAq2yXw*:APA91bH4GlHPSi[...]

Phone: *fnLVyZy_ICE*:APA91bHopxcL1ckHl[...]

Phone: *fnLVyZy_ICE*:CTVj02MDxjZq7rIYSi[...]

3. Server pushes notification and user now gets 1 notification on tablet and 2 on phone.

**How should this be handled? I can't be the only one with this problem**

The response i get from google when posting the notification from our server to FCM (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) is this:

```
{
  "multicast_id": 8013823232923765460,
  "success": 1,
  "failure": 0,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "message_id": "0:1482923896059583%2bb227d2f9fd7ecd"
    }
  ]
}
```

This response above applies for both the old GCM tokens and the new FCM tokens posted. No errors nor canonical_ids are set in the response so that our server may update accordingly.

Comment: I am wondering why you keep several tokens for one device. It is true that old tokens are valid for a while even when token is renewed. But it seems to me that you can update device tokens instead of keeping track of tokens, right?

Comment: The reason we save multiple token for a user is that he or she might have the app on several devices @AkramShokri. When server send push and gets invalid token back from GCM/FCM it will remove it from database. I thought for sure that the GCM generated one would come back as invalid on first push sent after user generated new one in FCM but thats not the case.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We are having the same problem. We updated form GCM to FCM but we also changed the google project, and now it seems like the old GCM tokens on the old project are still valid.

Comment: @Xzya. We haven't solved this in a proper way yet. We've done a workaround for now where we compare the first part of the token, before the colon (:), for the new and the old token for a user and remove the old token if the first part are the same. This is a ugly workaround that I don't like and this is not documented anywhere to always work but we saw this "pattern" and went for it for now. Still looking for a proper solution for this..

Answer (score 1):

You can have the logic on your client side (app) to send both the old token and new token so that you can update in your server database.

FCM token gets refreshed at times and even then the old token will be valid for sometime.

We have implemented this for web notification and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are not the only one experiencing this. I am also getting this same problem, where there are 2 valid notification ids (1 from GCM, 1 from FCM) for 1 device. User will get double notification.

One way I am doing it is to detect a fresh install by checking some default parameters in my own app-settings. This will be app-dependent and may not be fool-proof.

Answer (score 1):

actually, you don't have to store gcm tokens, just store fcm tokens.

FCM is still compatible with GCM, seeing as it is it's core. So switching to the FCM endpoint (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) when sending your notification should still work for your app versions that have GCM. No need to write separate programs.

so if you migrate and store new fcm tokens only, it will work and it is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did....
I was saving the oldToken in SharedPreference and got the newToken from Firebase
Basically if the oldToken is not same as newToken then delete it using GCM
Might need to do for initial upgrade versions then delete this code once majority of your users are on the new app version.

```
if (oldToken != null && !oldToken.equals(newToken) && newToken != null) {
        //Lets Delete the old Token, this is a blocking call and needs to happen in another thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(PMApplication.getContext()).deleteInstanceID();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //Nothing can be done, in this case we have to live with 2 tokens and 2 messages
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the migration guide from GCM to FCM:

> The FCM SDK automatically adds all required permissions as well as the required receiver funtionality. Make sure to remove the following obsolete (and potentially harmful, as they may cause message duplication) elements from your app's manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission android:name="<your-package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="<your-package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

...

<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

If I understand this correctly, it should be enough to remove those permissions in your manifest. By doing so GCM messages will not be received anymore. Just to be clear, I didn't test this!